# Calling Rails model from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

Is it considered a best practice to call a Rails model from another model ? (code below) :

```
#models/user.rb
def get_pending_requests(user_id)
  Friend.where("friend_id = ? AND approved = ?", user_id, false)
end
```

I find it a bit awkward to perform RSpec/FactoryGirl tests doing this, as opposed to perform these actions from within a Controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might I suggest a different approach?  Assuming that your models are setup like this:

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :pending, -> { where(approved: false) }
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friends

  def pending_requests
    friends.pending
  end
end
```

So you create a scope called pending on friend.  Then you can use that scope on your friends relation.  I find this to be a more standard approach.

Comment: I guess it should be self.friends, no ?
My example was not correctly illustrated though, I was thinking more of a `add_friend` method that would create a new record on `self.friends.new(...)`

Comment: It's not necessary unless you're expecting a collision between the friends method and a local variable called friends.

Comment: Yeah, you can do that.  In your `add_friend` method, you can do `self.friends.pending.create(...)`. That will create a pending friend with the id correctly set.

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm using now. But it's hell when it comes to testing. "Undefined table" errors and whatnot ..
Thank you for the feedback though !

Comment: This should not add any complexity at all to testing.  Perhaps consider updating your question with the specific errors that you are receiving.  We'd also need to see the tests/factories.  You must have something else going on.

Comment: I just submitted a new question to further explain my problem (this post was mainly to get a feedback of the best practice when calling models from models).
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127062/nested-models-testing-could-not-find-table-error
Thanks again.