# Nested models testing : Could not find table '*' Error.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to run RSpec against a `working` large codebase (I'm relatively new to Rails), but it fails on this point; My bet that it has something to do with the FactoryGirl definitions.

*Overview of the model :*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :friends, :conditions => {:approved => true}
  has_many :friendships, :class_name => "User", :source => :friend, :through => :friends
  # ...
```

*The method to test :*

```
# models/user.rb
def add_friend(user_id, friend_id)
  @friendship = self.friends.new({:user_id => user_id, :friend_id => friend_id})
  return false unless @friendship.save
end
```

*The FactoryGirl factories :*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, :class => User do |f|
    # ...
  end

  factory :friend, :class => Friend do |f|
    f.user_id     { Faker::Base.regexify(/\d{1,3}/)}
    f.friend_id   { Faker::Base.regexify(/\d{1,3}/)}
    # ...
  end
end
```

*The Spec :*

```
# specs/models/user_spec.rb
it "Adds friends" do
  @current_user.add_friend(@current_user.id, @friend_1.id).should be_valid
end
```

**The Error :**

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'friends'
```

Any feedback is highly welcome, Thanks.

Comment: Have you run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`?

Comment: What are the odds ... everything passes now (except 1 test, but that's good) !
I guess I didn't migrate the test db since ages :)

Comment: (Can you please add your answer so I can mark the post as resolved ?)

Comment: It's always the little things, huh?  I just added the answer.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`.